# file not found exception loading properties file in izpack

Tags: java, izpack

I am trying to load the properties file with my custom panel using IZpack 4.3.5.
i have placed all the properties and images related to my isntaller in bin folder of izpack and created install.jar.when i tried to run it it is working fine .

But when  i run the same jar in the some other folder/mechine i am getting file not found exception of .properties file in my custompanel.java class.
Could you tell me how to give the relativepath/path to load the properties file using my custompanel?

i added following in install.xml

```
<resources>
<res id='template.properties" src="template.properties>
<resources>

<panel classname="custompanel"/>

<packs>
<pack name="Base" required="yes">
<file src="template.properties" targetDir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
<parseble targetfile="template.properties" type="prop" parse="yes"/>
<pack>
</packs>
```

in my custom class

inputstream in=new FileinputStream("template.properties"); -------------------------------exception coming here (file not found template.properties)

Can you please let me know how to solve this in IZpack 4.3.5 or how to provide/get the relative path of the template.properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create the install.jar, the file is not available in the file system. It is part of the jar. Use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("template.properties")` to access the file.

Comment: Hi I did the change you mentioned,i am getting null pointer exception at line..can you let me know how to resolve that.

Comment: Use `jar tvf installer.jar` and find the path to the template.properties file. Use that path in the call to `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: thanks alot..you saved my day.can you let me know how to get the same file as output stream to update the properties?

Comment: You can't get the output stream, because that requires updating the JAR. What we usually do in these cases is to write custom properties into a file in a known location (may be users home folder) and the loading logic loads the internal file first and then loads the custom file. If this solved your issue, please accept the answer.